# passing multiple values in the case statement of where clause in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I need to get input from the user which will be passed to the query and compared with the existing value AA. If it is AA then the ABC schema will be selected.

The below query works fine,

```
select distinct a.TABLE_OWNER,a.table_name,a.index_name,b.column_name
from dba_indexes a, dba_ind_columns b
where a.index_name=b.index_name 
and a.table_name = b.table_name
and a.table_owner in ( case when &user_input = 'AA' then 'ABC' end )
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

but if I have to mention one more schema name like, DEF, how will I do it. I tried using comma, but it is throwing error, "missing right parenthesis"

```
select distinct a.TABLE_OWNER,a.table_name,a.index_name,b.column_name
from dba_indexes a, dba_ind_columns b
where a.index_name=b.index_name 
and a.table_name = b.table_name
and a.table_owner in ( case when &user_input = 'AA' then 'ABC','DEF' end )
order by 1,2,3,4;
```

error

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 5 Column: 63
```

I read from Ask Tom website that, only a scalar value can be returned, is it possible to return a bunch of values ?

Comment: Help us understand the logic first. If we understand the logic, the code should be easy to fix. So: Are you looking to require that `a.table_owner` be in `('ABC', 'DEF')`, but this is required only when `&user_input = 'AA'`? What if `&user_input` is not `'AA'`? Do you not require ANY condition then? It seems so, from the pseudo-code you wrote; just making sure that is correct.

Comment: @mathguy yes, what you are saying is correct. If the &userinput is not 'AA' I can use an else clause. But I just want to know if case can help me in this situation.

Comment: @Mrk A `CASE` expression normally can't return a range of values, so your current query won't fly.

Comment: `case` can help sometimes (when you want to enforce a specific order of evaluation of logical conditions), but it must be written carefully. It seems in your situation you just need proper use of `AND` and `OR` operators, you don't need `CASE` expressions. Note that Oracle SQL does not have BOOLEAN data type, so there is no such thing as "CASE condition" - which is what you were probably thinking of.

Comment: @mathguy okay, got your point. Thank you for your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a correct way to use CASE in the WHERE clause.

```
...
and case &user_input when 'AA' then case when a.table_owner in ('ABC', DEF') then 1 end
                     else           case when <your other conditions here>   then 1 end
    end
    = 1
```

How it works:

First `&user_input` is compared to 'AA'. If true, `a.table_owner` is compared to 'ABC' and 'DEF', if it's one of them the `CASE` expression has the value 1, otherwise NULL (by default). If `&user_input` is not 'AA' (it may also be NULL), then the other conditions, which you didn't state, are evaluated, and if true, the `CASE` expression evaluates to 1, otherwise to NULL.

Then compare the result of the `CASE` expression with the number 1.

One benefit is this: If the "other conditions" are expensive (a lot of computations, whatnot), this arrangement guarantees that they will not be performed, if `&user_input` is 'AA', due to short-circuit evaluation. You have **no such control** if you write the conditions with `AND` and `OR` operators alone.

Note also the NESTING of CASE expressions within the outer CASE - this is perfectly valid and helpful in many situations.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `case` for this.  I think you intend:

```
and ( &user_input <> 'AA' or a.table_owner in ('ABC','DEF') )
```

This is speculation.  The current code is more like:

```
and ( &user_input = 'AA' and a.table_owner in ('ABC','DEF') )
```

because the `case` has no `else` clause.

Comment: If `&user_input` may be `NULL`, that will also have to be handled; the first version will require the table owner to be 'ABC' or 'DEF' in that case, and it's not clear that was the intent.

Answer (score 1):

A `CASE` expression must generate a single scalar value as far as I know.  But you can rewrite your `WHERE` clause as follows:

```
where
    a.index_name = b.index_name and
    a.table_name = b.table_name and
    (&user_input = 'AA' and
    a.table_owner in ('ABC', 'DEF') )
```